# Strong gravitational force induced by static electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

This 2004 [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0407048) by B V Ivanov claims that static electromagnetic fields can create strong gravitational fields. He claims a capacitor charged to 100 kV loses 1% of its weight and a capacitor charged to 6 MV would levitate. This has long been claimed as the origin of the [Biefeld-Brown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biefeld%E2%80%93Brown_effect) effect as opposed to the conventional explanation of ionic wind thrust. Ivanov seems to use a sophisticated general relativity argument to make his claims but he hasn’t managed to publish the result.

Abstract

> It is argued that static electric or magnetic fields induce
> Weyl-Majumdar-Papapetrou solutions for the metric of spacetime. Their
> gravitational acceleration includes a term many orders of magnitude
> stronger than usual perturbative terms. It gives rise to a number of
> effects, which can be detected experimentally. Four electrostatic and
> four magnetostatic examples of physical set-ups with simple symmetries
> are proposed. The different ways in which mass sources enter and
> complicate the pure electromagnetic picture are described.

He claims that the Weyl-Majumdar-Papapetrou fields imply that the gravitational force on a test particle $g_\mu$ is given by

$$g_\mu=c^2f^{-1}\Big(\frac{B}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{8\pi}}\bar{\phi}_\mu+\frac{\kappa}{8\pi}\bar{\phi}\bar{\phi}_\mu\Big),$$
where $\bar{\phi}$ is the electrostatic potential, $E_\mu=-\bar{\phi}_\mu$ is the electric field and $f=1+B\phi+\phi^2$ is a solution of the so-called Weyl field (see the section II Root Gravity).

He says that the coefficient of the first linear term is $10^{23}$ times bigger than the coefficient of the second quadratic term. The quadratic latter term is familiar from standard perturbation theory. This accounts for the anomalously large gravitational effect of the electrostatic field in this case.

Does his argument make sense?

Comment: Please use hyperlinks for the abstract and not for the PDF file.

Comment: Ok - I've done that.

Comment: There is a Physics SE policy that we don't generally review individual papers and I think in the case of an unpublished one (arxiv is not "published" in this sense) this would be more likely rather than less.  I would say offhand that the apparent lack of publication and experiment in 18 years is problematic, but the material is not something I would be competent to comment on in detail anyway.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine in this case the author seems to have been decently known in his field, as is the institute he was from. As for papers which have cited this 2004 preprint, only one of them seems to be legit - but the author (Victor Varela) just briefly mentions that it's an "interesting physical and mathematical aspects of Majumdar-type solutions.". Sometimes this kind of thing happens with well-known theoretical researchers, where they put a small paper up on the arxiv that somehow never makes it to a journal, and yet years later everyone knows about it.

Comment: This is pure, irresponsible speculation -- I haven't read the paper or worked through the details. But, as an off-the-cuff first impression, "an unusually large first order term that is bigger than the leading second order term you see in ordinary perturbation theory" sounds a lot like an unphysical gauge artifact. In other words, if it turned out that the first order term was an artifact of a particular choice of coordinates and ends up canceling out when you compute an observable quantity, I would not be surprised.

Comment: @Andrew: but an acceleration is a measurable quantity, right?  I agree that there is almost certainly some smoke or mirrors or slight of hand going on here, though.

Comment: Charge does produce gravitational repulsion, see the Reissner Nordström Repulsion but that Repulsion falls off faster than 1/r², so it is only gravitationally repulsive to neutral particles at close range, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718176/does-a-charged-particle-respond-to-a-charged-black-hole-both-gravitationally-and/718183#718183

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Yes, but what's computed here is a 4-force, which presumably is meant to appear on the right hand side of the geodesic equation. If they were using a non-affine parameter then the geodesic equation would have extra terms which could cancel the "force". Anyway that's just an example of the kind of thing that *could* be going on. To be very clear I haven't worked through the details. I just know I have seen many surprising claims about gravity of the form "there's an unusually large term which doesn't appear in other calculations" boil down to a mistake involving gauge invariance.

Comment: If you could cause a capacitor to levitate by charging it to 6 MV then you could discharge it and make it do work as it fell under the Earth’s gravity. By repeating wouldn’t you have a source of free energy?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good illustration of what happens when one forget that

**Correlation  does not imply causation.**

Yes, the author of the cited paper correctly describes a family of solutions of Einstein field equations with electrostatic fields. Within this family gravitational force (in the static frame) does behave according to the equation reproduced by OP. However, the conclusion drawn from that equation, that electric field *causes* this gravitational force is wrong. Rather both gravitational force and electrostatic field share the same cause: distribution of charged matter with a specific constant *charge-to-mass* ratio. But it is the “mass part” of this matter distribution that is mainly responsible for the gravitational field (long range electrostatic field contributes what amounts to a tiny correction under conditions of a reasonable experiment). So all claims made by the author (and by other authors relying on this paper) “derived” from the behavior of this solution family extrapolating the effects on situations without the constraints on  charge and mass densities are unfounded.

Note that Majumdar–Papapetrou family has a lot of solutions with interesting properties such as [multicenter black hole solutions](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01645696) and [almost black holes](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.69.104004). In all such solutions with strongly curved spacetimes variation of the electrostatic potential between the asymptotic region and strongly curved region is of order of *Planck voltage* which is unity in GR units or $c^2/\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0 G}\approx 1.04 \times 10^{27} \text{ V}$ in SI units (see [this PSE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/656340/180269) for the discussion of Planck voltage). So if we consider MP solutions with potential  variations much smaller than $10^{27}\text{ V}$ these solutions would be *almost flat* and since they are also static, to analyze them one would only need the Newtonian gravity together with equations of electrostatic. So this is what we'll do.

Let us assume that we have a system of charges at rest with constant charge to mass ratio given by (in SI units):
$$
\frac{q}m =\sqrt{4πϵ_0 G }\approx 8.62\times10^{-11}~\text{C}\cdot\text{kg}^{-1}. \tag{*}
$$
This corresponds to about one elementary charge for about $10^{18}$ nucleon masses. It is easy to see that in this system the force of gravitational attraction acting on each charge is precisely compensated by the force of Coulomb repulsion:
$$
\mathbf{F_\text{g}}=-\sum_i\frac{G\, m m_i \,\mathbf{r}_i }{r_i^3}=- \sum_i\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q q_i \,\mathbf{r}_i }{r_i^3} = - \mathbf{F}_\text{e}.
$$
So this system of charges initially at rest would remain at rest indefinitely. And Newtonian gravitational and electrostatic potentials are related via:
$$ 
\phi_\text{g}=-\sqrt{4πϵ_0 G} |\phi_\text{e}|.
$$
To reiterate, while this last equation has $\sqrt{G}$ and electrostatic potential on the rhs, it does not mean that electric field *causes* this gravitational field.

Now, imagine the system of MP charges is placed in external (Newtonian) gravitational field. If this external field is approximately homogeneous on a  scale of MP subsystem then it would move as a single body possessing mass and charge (satisfying $(*)$) and would also generally undergo deformations by tidal forces. But there would not be any unusual “antigravity” (or other paradoxical) effects. And if the MP subsystem is mechanically connected to some structure neutralizing its charge (such as a plate of capacitor) there would by no unusual gravitational of electromagnetic effects.